# How to backup in Fedora-13?

Tags: backup, fedora-13

I just bought a 1.5T HDD and a disk enclosure. I connected this disk to my laptop via the provided USB cable. I then used the following command:

```
rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -c -l -z / /media/C4E41A11E41A0678/Moonface_BKP/
```

I ran this for a long (long long) time when i noticed that what had been backed up to the HDD began to be backed up. In other words, when i ran the command, it created a /media directory and a C4... directory below that and kept recursively backing up this directory (since, I suppose, I was backing up the hard drive itself, too).

So...what's the proper way to use rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favorite way to backup on Linux is [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/). It's basically a frontend for rsync oriented towards backup, but it's extremely easy.

---

But for your rsync command, I'm pretty sure you can get away with just syncing /home which is where anything irreplaceable is anyway, so you could run

```
rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete -c -l -z /home/ /media/C4E41A11E41A0678/Moonface_BKP/
```

or if you really need to just exclude `/media`,

```
rsync -r -t -v --progress --delete --exclude /media/ -c -l -z / /media/C4E41A11E41A0678/Moonface_BKP/
```

You may also want to include `-a` and combine the other letters, making your end result

```
rsync -arvcz --progress --delete --exclude /media/ / /media/C4E41A11E41A0678/Moonface_BKP/
```

Comment: i think their might be a typo? should that instead be -z /home/?

Comment: @Ramy updated. Actually, come to think of it, I don't think -z is a good idea either. It only compresses on data transfer, which while makes it a bit faster (this is on the fly compression, not that good), will also strain on the CPU.

Comment: ah, ok. cool. Thanks for all the info and help!